# disprove : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n<m<n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I figured this would be easier to solve if I thought of it as proving and existential statement and ended up with  $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}\ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge m \ge$. Now I'm stuck.  Is the only way that statement can be true is if $n =m$, but that doesn't really disprove the original statement. At least I don't think it does. Any suggestion about how to go about this problem?

Comment: $1 \not< 1^2=1 $

Comment: Hint: This is equivalent to finding an $n$ such that $n^2 \leq n+1$. Can you think of such an $n$?

Comment: Your first sentence is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true for $n = 1$. (because $n = n^2$)

But if $n>1$ then:

$n \ge 2$.  Let $m = n + 1$ so

$ n < m =n + 1  < n + n = 2*n \le n*n = n^2 $.

=====

'nother proof.

Let $n \ge 2$.  Then $n^2 - n = n(n - 1) \ge 2*1 = 2$.  So there is at least one natural number between $n$ and $n^2$.

======

third proof:

If there is *no* such m.  Then either:

1:  $n^2 = n + 1$.  But that is impossible ans $n^2 - n - 1 = 0$ has no rational roots.

2: $n^2 = n$.  Then $n(n - 1) = 0$ so $n = 1$ or $n = 0$.

3: $n^2 < n$.  As $0^2 = 0$, $n \ne 0$. So as N is natural number $n \gt 0$.  So $n^2/n < n/n$ so $n < 1$ which contradicts that $n$ is a natural number.  So this is impossible.

Conclusion:  $n = 1$ or $n = 0$ (If you are using the definition that 0 is a natural number. Most mathematicians use the definition that 0 isn't a natural number.)

Comment: wait what?  I don't quite follow

Comment: n is bigger or equal to 2.  So n x n is bigger or equal to 2 x n.  2 x n = n + n.  n is bigger than 1 so n + n is bigger than n + 1.  And n + 1 is bigger than n.

So $n^2$ > n + 1 > n.  Let m = n + 1.